# Switch from ADF to React

Tags: reactjs, oracle-adf, jdeveloper-11g

How do you switch your frontend stack from ADF to React?

Currently, JDeveloper 11g 11.1.2.4.0 and JRE 1.6 are used. There would be a switch from ADF to React as front-end technology while keeping java for backend.

Some features have been already tested/implemented by React within an iframe. I have found many resources about how to migrate react, top to bottom, bottom to top approaches. However, I could not find any similar case study where these 2 technologies (ADF, React) were switched. Here is an excellent case from stripe about how to switch from [flow to typescript](https://stripe.com/blog/migrating-to-typescript).

I would like to get similar information, like in the article attached above, regarding switching from ADF to React in order to have a `rough guide` to follow, this way avoiding pitfalls.

Comment: The technology are too different. Java and JavaScript have nothing in common. You're better off treating this as a new project with new specifications.

Comment: I might have not been clear enough. I am aware of that JavaScript and Java have nothing in common. ADF part should be switched to React, which means we want to get rid of the `jsf`, `jsff` and `jspx` files and use simple html for react. Communication between frontend (React) and backend (Java) would be done by webservices at first. At least for the test features it was done by webservices. Thank you for your feedback @Cedric